# Visit Heroku database and connect to local MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, heroku

I have deployed a Django app in Heroku. It has some log-in function and data fill-in function. I want to know where is this information stored? How could I visit them?

In addition, in the Django app, I have add some function that connect to local MySQL database. But in the web deployed, the connection is refused. How could I deal with the problem?  I am quite new in Heroku.

Here's the setting and view parts.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "bootstrap3",
    # my application
    "learning_logs.apps.LearningLogsConfig",
    "users.apps.UsersConfig",
    "django_forms_bootstrap",
    "ncbi_crawler",
)
DATABASES = {

    #'default': {
    #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    #}

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mall',
        'USER': 'rinka',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

This the view part.

```
def results(request):
    data=[]
    data1 = []
    owner = request.user
    owner = str(owner)
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='crawling', passwd='xxxx', host='localhost')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT search_content, pmid, journal, title, author, institute, abstract, article_info FROM result_split where username = '%s'" % (owner))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close()
    return render(request, "learning_logs/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deployed your app using git (`git push heroku master`) route then you can always connect from "heroku cli" by commands like `heroku run python manage.py dbshell`

Note - you won't be able to access your local database ( I assume you mean database on your laptop/desktop/machine whatever you use for your work) on Heroku instance.

Comment: Thx. So if I cannot connect to localhost database on heroku, how could I manage the data from the user? I have add ClearDB in heroku, is that the way?

Comment: is it possible for you to share your "settings.py" file content? Share DATABASE details here.

Comment: Sure. I will added in the question part.